# Local DNS Resolution Forcing Sites to https://www. Immediately Following LE SSL Certificate Attainment

Tags: networking, dns

The oddest DNS problem that I have seen.

**Situation:**
On my prod server, all my domains work correctly when they have self-signed SSL certificates. On my local machine all of my domains on the prod server correctly display in my web browsers at:
`https://example.com`  (after I accept the browser warning about self signed ssl certificates)

**Problem:**
Immediately following successfully attaining a Let's Encrypt SSL for any of my domains on the prod server, results in all of my local web browsers being unable to load `https://example.com`. However,  (the weird part)  `https://www.example.com` works perfectly correctly.

**Testing:**
1.) I booted into my Windows 10 partition and confirmed that both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` both load correctly in any web browser.

2.) A friend on his home network, confirmed that `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` both load in his local browsers without any problems.

Only in ubuntu 20.04 on my local machine will `https://example.com` refuse to load in any web browser after the LE SSL has been attained.

**Unique Aspect:**

The only thing that is unique about my Ubuntu 20.04 set-up is that I run a vbox test server and use dnsmasq for local DNS resolution (which may be irrelevant info).  Minus all the extra stuff my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` settings are:

```
port=53
bogus-priv
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.58.1
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
domain=example-site.test
```

I also run a wireguard server of the remote server / wireguard client on local machine (however this problem persists regardless of whether I am connected to wireguard or not)

if I use `$nslookup prod-server-domain.com`  it correctly shows me:

```
nslookup prod-server-domain.org
Server:     192.xxx.xx.xx   <--- wireguard server ip
Address:    192.xxx.xx.xx#53  <--- wireguard server ip

Name:   prod-server-domain.org
Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx        <--- public prod server ip
```

**Simplified Even More:**
Following the successful attainment of LE SSL certificates for my remote server's domain names, on every web browser in the the world **-except-** my local ubuntu web browsers the urls `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` both work correctly as expected leading to the exact same website.

Only in my ubuntu installation does `https://example.com` FAIL

Whereas `https://www.example.com` WORKS.

When I open `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` in web browsers on my Windows partition on the same home network, with the same ip adddress, both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` **both work correctly**.

**Additional Info:**

1. The domains all point at the correct IP address
2. I have the same problem if I completely deactivate UFW and Wireguard
3. The SSL is being attained via Virtualmin, which confirms the correct url submissions for LE SSL assignment:

   [image]

   (all say example.org)

   [image]

Firefox and all other browsers show this error for `https://example.org`
[image]
Whereas this works perfectly in all browsers:
[image]

```
user@machine:~$ curl example.org
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.org port 80: No route to host
user@machine:~$ curl https://example.org
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.org port 443: No route to host
user@machine:~$ curl https://www.example.org
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Virtualmin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Per request:

```
$ ip route list
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.13 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.18 metric 600
```

Comment: DNS is not able to force you to HTTPS or not, it has nothing to do with the protocols your system communicates with servers and systems.  DNS is just "What IP does the domain point to".  HSTS and other firewall rules and proxies will be breaking HTTPS.  What happens when you try and go go to example.com?  How did you create the SSL certificate (because if you don't have the proper domains in the cert it won't work)?  What's the actual error messages you get/see?

Comment: @ThomasWard  Answered your questions with additional info in the post

Comment: Can you on the command line run `curl https://example.com` (use your real domain!) and copy/paste the output (or error message as there likely will be)?  This error message you're showing suggests that something in your domain setup is wrong with the SSL certificate due to a connection error (possible SSL negotiation problem or badness at play)

Comment: Let me guess... someone may be trying to intercept my data and screwed up the tap....  sound about right?

Comment: and we are sure that example.com points to the same IP as www.example.com yes?  (impossible to determine with you obfuscating the dns results)

Comment: absolutely sure... ISP does not use a public/private server ip system...   just old fashion single  ip virtual machine... actually costs extra for for a private ip...

Comment: What does `ip route list` say? Do you have setup a correct routing table for the given IP Address? (Windows pendant is `route print`, this should show comparable results)
Does the VPN config enforce the IP address to be routed via the VPN? Does it take over the default route? Does the VPN server have the correct routes configured for the incoming connections via VPN?

Comment: @cyberbrain I added the ip route list info to the post above.  I understand that you suspect the vpn.  However, as I mention, the same persists regardless of whether the vpn is connected or not. I use wireguard and all traffic is routed through the vpn when it is connected.  On the same computer's window drive, example.com & www.example.com both work correctly.   On ubuntu example.com works correctly with self-signed certificates.  The problem is only triggered afte LE SSL is attained.

Comment: Well, I just want to be sure about VPN, if you definitely can tick it off the list of suspects its better ;) The routes you added are without active VPN, right? So you have two default routes going to the same gateway, once via LAN and once via WiFi. What is a bit suspicious for me is the active APIPA route on eth0 (169.254.x.x), but some more important questions: Can you try if turning off either LAN or WiFi changes the problematic situation for you? I hope both interfaces have different IP addresses. Does Windows also have that dual Interface setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

I use dnsmasq and my external DNS server had stopped working.

I chose new external DNS servers and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

compare the results of `$nslookup prod-server-domain.com` and `$www.nslookup prod-server-domain.com`. Are they really pointing to the same ip?

Comment: Yes, the $nslookup results for example.com and www.example.com point to exactly the same IP address

Answer (score -1):

I assume your local self-signed certificates do work either by accepting the risk notification in your browsers, you having added them into your local certificate management server oder the local machine keyring.

First understand that Https://www.test.org is per www-standard not a subdomain like Https://toast.test.org but an immediate redirector to Https://test.org. Even when seperate values are entered in a local DNS that service should complain that you are trying to redirect the same index to two different targets.

Second I saw is that you SSL certificate uses a wildcard. While wildcards are handy as only one SSL certificate is needed to be maintained wildcard certificates hamper network security.
I highly advise you to stay far away from those and actually setup a proper local certificate management.

While I am not 100% sure it is likely that your local setups and entries do stop a proper redirect once a real certificate is in place on the server. Usually setting up a certificate on a server will invalidate any local self-signed certificates previously pointing to it. Usually this is greeted with a oopsidaisy this server changed its certificate are you really sure you wanna go there m8 warning.

The only place your DNS entry should be pointing towards is Https://test.org -> x.x.x.x
For your main service. As said previously the WWW should not make a difference as it is a redirect to the above.

Try to free your clients browsers and OS key chains from all this invalid self-signed certificates and the Webservice should work as intended.
Mind you if your server is not an exposed host your need to make sure that outside requests are routed from your web entry point to your server.

Comment: I don't have a problem with local self-signed certificates. This seems like careful jibberish, perhaps spam..

Comment: In that case I misunderstood your initial post and the information contained in it.

Comment: I edited the post.  Hopefully, things are more clear.. if you edit your post I will change my vote.

Comment: @nightwatch Be a little careful *bargaining* with votes in this manner, make your vote up or down and leave it at that. Certainly seek *clarity* in the comments and allow this to influence your vote...

Comment: @andrew.46  Ok.. my bad.  I just didn't want to incorrectly vote down something possibly caused by my own unclear writing.  In any case, I l will eave the vote as is. I don't think folks are grasping my problem because it is so odd and unique, most likely caused by my home network being incorrectly tapped.